# Sorting by value in R without dplyr or packages in general

Tags: r, sum

I'm a beginner in R language and currently working with a large set of data and I've simplified the situation as follows:

```
apples = sum(1+1)  
oranges = sum(1+3)   
kiwis = sum(1+2)  
grapes = sum(1+5)  
banana = sum(1+4)
```

After applying sum(), is there a way to display like :

> grapes = 6, banana = 5, oranges = 4, kiwis = 3, apples = 2

from highest count to lowest count?

Please help me out.

Really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to (a) combine into a single vector or list, (b) reverse-sort, and (c) change how R displays named vectors/lists?

Comment: hey there. appreciate the advice on (a) and (b) please. @r2evans

Comment: `sort(unlist(data.frame(apples,oranges,kiwis,grapes,banana)), decreasing = TRUE)`? The use of `data.frame` is really just a cheat to name the vector without having to include it twice, though `sort(setNames(c(apples,oranges,kiwis,grapes,banana), c("apples","oranges","kiwis","grapes","banana")), decreasing = TRUE)` produces the same result without the `data.frame`-hack.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the complete breakdown!